# how could I compile ASP Jscript (ASP Classic) to DLL?

Tags: javascript, dll, asp-classic

Yeah, I'm asking 'bout ASP classic - which was invented in 1999. as old as my grandma. But why bother if it still help me finish my tasks?

Okay, now, a little about what i'm trying to do : I have my software base on ASP JScript (classic). I must give my client all the ASP Code when project finish, but I wanna keep the secret about the core functions in my project.

I've spent plenty much of time on searching for "ASP Encryption" & eventually realize that code encryption is - anyway - not a 100% safe approach.

I think to encapsulate all the functions & classes in my file named "CORE_Lib.asp" to a DLL file is better & absolutely safe. THe story start here...

I've used Visual Basic 6.0 to create "a simple dll", yeah, it run good. But I'm used to code with JScript, and still haven't found out such an equivalent IDE for JScript like Visual Studio.

BTW, I know there's something that very difference between JScript & Visual Basic, kinda JScript (or JavaScript) is just a minor script language run with Windows Script Host, while 
VB is a very well equiped.

I hope I described enough for you to get a view of what's I'm facing. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *But why bother if it still help me finish my tasks?*: because there are modern tools that will allow you to do the job faster, easier, better with fewer hassles and errors. Maintaining old platforms is OK, but writing new code and features using things like Classic ASP is like committing a crime against the developers community.

Comment: Relax.  No one is going to steal your ASP Classic code.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov
ASP Classic is my best choice 'cause I can put "IIS 5.1 Installer" inside software setup file. (just 10Mb). ASP Classic is the native language for this kinda server. I found it's the easiest way to develope a network-software.

Comment: @smartcaveman
I don't want my client to see the code for one more important reason : the license checkup logic is there inside the code.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon, Your client can't see server-side code.  The code is processed and then rendered as HTML.  Regardless, see my answer for a solution

Comment: Please notice what i wrote above. I said that I must give my client all   ASP source codes. The code runs under IIS-that is install on the client computer. This software is kinda a local website with a "winform-cover". Actually, it's just IE instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an ASP Classic script by loading a file as plain text, right?  I think it's `Server.Execute`.  And since your only concern is protecting the code, you could save it in an encrypted format, then load and decrypt files to temporary locations and execute them as needed.  This seems like it would solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks smartcaveman for your answer.But Server.Execute() runs its own way. What happend in the file to be executed doeasn't affect the rest of the running file.
Another issue is that to create temporary file each time I run it may slow down the software.